# What permissions are needed to edit Mosaico templates?

Tags: civimail, permissions, templates

My guess it that template creation and editing requires Administer CiviCRM - but wanted to check in and see if there was another way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the permissions for message templates and system workflow messages do not apply to editing Mosaico Templates.

I could not grant access to mosaico templates without granting the Administer CiviCRM permission.

Answer (score 1):

I guess below permission are required fro user to update the mosaico template

1. CiviCRM: edit message templates
2. CiviCRM: edit system workflow message templates